# Delphi XE10.2.3 iOS device System status bar

Tags: ios, delphi, statusbar

I have installed *Delphi 10.2.3* and I have a problem with the apps for *iOS*.

When  I compile a basic application on *iOS* device (I have tested on *iPhone 6*), 
there is no space between the application screen and the system status bar, on *iOS* Simulator yes.

I have checked the new form property `SystemStatusBar` and it's flagged as visible.

Anybody Knows what is the problem?

The iOs version is 11.2.6 with xcode Version 8.0.

This is a screen of the app with Embarcadero Tokyo

[image: Screen Tokyo]

and this is the app screen with Berlin

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Which version of iOS does the device have? Can you post a picture of the screen that does not have the status bar?

Comment: @DaveNottage I edited the main post with the information. Sorry.

Comment: You said: "..system status bar is not visible". In your picture the status bar is visible, so please explain the true nature of the problem

Comment: @DaveNottage sorry, I think I've explained wrong, the system status bar looks, but overlaps with the toolbar, also is not that the color you should have. I edited again the main post. Sorry and thank you.

Comment: Then you need to edit your question, because the status bar is visible, just not in the place you're expecting. The answer is that for iOS 11, the screen area has changed. If you want it to look the same, you'll need to allow for it by adding layouts as suggested in this article: http://delphiworlds.com/2017/11/supporting-iphone-x-display-with-delphi/

Comment: @DaveNottage Ok, Thank you.

Comment: I found the same behavior, but it only happens on iOS 11. On iOs 9 + 10, it behaves like your Berlin screen shot, even when compiled with Tokyo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently using XCode 8.0. I had this exact same issue (on an actual device, not on a simulator) when I was using XCode 8.2 (SDK 10.2). Today I upgraded to XCode 9.2, and SDK 11.2. Now it works like you would expect.

So current specs for my setup is: RAD 10.2.3, SDK 11.2, iOS 11.3.1, XCode 9.2.

Make sure to download XCode 9.2 and not 9.3, as SDK 11.3 (which is offered by XCode 9.3) will not compile with Delphi 10.2.3 as of right now. You can download old XCode versions from your apple developer account, follow this link: https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode

To install new SDKs on RAD Studio, first delete all of your old ones in Tools -> Options -> SDK Manager. Then delete all the local files at User -> Documents -> Embarcadero -> Studio -> SDKs.
After this is done, upgrade XCode, set up a connection profile (Tools -> Options -> Connection Profile Manager), then enter SDK Manager and you should be given the option to install SDK 11.2. If you are using TMS ICL components, you need to add some library paths or you will get a compiler error.

Hope this helps!

Also adding that this behaviour with 10.2.3 seems exclusive to iOS 11 or newer, I tested this on a device with iOS 10.2 and the problem disappeared.

PS: I would recommend installing iOS 11.3 or newer, as there are a lot of fixes that handles some problems between Delphi and iOS (comboboxes not scrolling, labels not displaying the correct text and some performance issues).